# VueJS does not bind inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, data-binding, vue.js

I have a VueJs code that used to work fine until I decided to put it into an iframe, then it is no longer binding data.

this is my code:

**HTML (GLOBAL)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="appbar">
      <iframe src="/auth"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**IFRAME CONTENT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bower/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="auth">
    <div>{{foo}}</div>
    <script src="js/auth.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var auth = new Vue({
    el: '#auth',
    data: {
        foo: "I'm a text but don't appear"
    }
})
```

And this what I get:

[image]

And the javascript seems to be working fine, when I tap in console `auth.foo` I get the right value:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works using Vue 1.x.  I copied your code locally into .html files and it worked fine.  I just changed the script tag to point to a 1.x version of Vue on a CDN.

If you're using Vue 2.x, you can't bind to the body element anymore.  Add a `div` with an `id` of auth and your code works fine in Vue 2.x:

```
  <body>
    <div id="auth">
        <div>{{foo}}</div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/auth.js"></script>
  </body>
```